# Powershell script to send files in a folder to an API in alphabetical order

Tags: powershell

I struggle with my ps-script to send files from a folder to an API in alphabetical order. I also need to let the script sleep for 10 seconds after 2 files being sent. I am trying to send each file 100 x to this api, so that's why I used 1..100 there and using $command to see my progress, but that already works so that's why I didn't post the rest of my script.

Any help is appriciated, I came up with this:

```
$url = "https://anywebserver"    
$localfolder = "c:\folder"
Set-Location $localfolder
$localfiles = Get-ChildItem $localfolder | Sort-Object -Descending

$count=0
ForEach ($LocalFile in $localfiles) 
{
    if(++$count %2 eq 0)
    { 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 
    }
    $command = [scriptblock]{(1..100|%{result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -InFile "$LocalFile -Uri $url;})}
}
```

Comment: What result are you currently getting from your script?

Comment: it looks like its counting 2 files in the folder and sleeping 10 seconds and after its done doing it for the whole list of files it executes $command line without applying the 10 seconds sleep. i am also not sure if its taking those files in alphabetical order. is there a way to confirm that?

Comment: Your ForEach command should be processing them in the order it encounters them. You could check the order it's finding them in with `ForEach ($LocalFile in $localfiles) {Write-Host $LocalFile}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the following is helpful in showing how to take 2 files at a time in alphabetical order.  I've changed the 1..100 to 1..2 and the sleep to 1 second for speed of testing, these can obviously be changed to your preferred values.

```
$skip = 0
$copy = 1

$path = "c:\folder"

while(gci $path | ?{! $_.PSIsContainer} | sort Name | select -skip $skip | select -first 2){
    
    $filesToCopy = gci $path | ?{! $_.PSIsContainer} | sort Name | select -skip $skip | select -first 2
    
    1..2 | %{
    
        #Perform copy
        $filesToCopy
        write-output "Copy Number $copy Complete"
        Start-Sleep 1
    }

    $skip = $skip + 2
    $copy++

}
```

Comment: Hi Nimizen, thanks a lot! i feel like i am really close to the solution with your answer. i just need to embed invoke-restmethod line in to this script. can u help me with that? i tried to put it below $filestocopy and i changed the InFile paramater from $LocalFile to $filestocopy, now it runs and i see it sends the files 2 by 2 but after each iteration of 2 files it says also invoke-restmethod cannot find path c:\folder\filename.extension because it doesnt exist

Comment: Think of the $filesToCopy variable as an object that contains both files, you need to reference each file like $fileToCopy.Item(0).Fullname and $fileToCopy.Item(1).Fullname OR you could nest another foreach like foreach($file in $filesToCopy){#do stuff}.

Comment: thanks m8, i added foreach file with invoke-restmethod and it seems like its working now. i will test it on monday, hopefully its done. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Your `Start-Sleep` is running outside of the loop which is writing the data., so all it's doing is sleeping, then running all one hundred POST requests with no Sleep inbetween them. You want something more like this:

```
$url = "https://anywebserver"    
$localfolder = "c:\folder"
Set-Location $localfolder
$localfiles = Get-ChildItem $localfolder | Sort-Object -Descending

$count=0
ForEach ($LocalFile in $localfiles) 
{
    $command = [scriptblock]{
        For($i=1;$i -le 100;$i++){
            result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -InFile $LocalFile -Uri $url;
            if(($i % 2) -eq 0){Start-Sleep -Seconds 10}
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, i tried ur suggestion but it gives me an error on "eq", says unexptected token... also an error on missing closing ')' .... thanks for your time and help..

Comment: @Tylendis - Aha, error inherited from your script. You need to call `-eq` to trigger the comparison. It doesn't recognise `eq` without it. Amended code above.

Comment: Duh! *facepalm* thanks! :D, also, how do i know if the command is using the $localfiles in descending order? is the way i put it on my script correct? or is there a way to see that? when i write $localfiles it shows me in descending order. but i am not sure if its using it in that order, or is that by default ?

Comment: @Tylendis - see my last comment in your Question. Try running the loop but with a `Write-Host` to show you what order it's handling them in.

Comment: @Tylendis - one good habit to get into is giving yourself a more visual indication of what the script is doing. Until you're confident in what is happening, put in lines occasionally to write output to the screen or to a logfile for troubleshooting.

Comment: @ Steve, thanks for the advice, i will try to do that, write-host is giving me indeed the order it was reading it in. thanks for that one. i just have one question left. the sleep seconds after 2 files being processed seems like not working. the script doesnt give me any error so it seems fine but its not doing what it should do. i have 11 files in that folder, it should take at least 1 minute to complete the script, but it takes 10 seconds to complete.

Comment: @Tylendis - right, so I haven't tried embedding a counter inside a pipeline function like this. One of the usual advantages of the Pipeline is *parallel processing* - so it is able to run multiple lines at once. I think what is probably happening is that it's running many of your 1..100 lines in parallel, and not sharing your counter between them. Have tried changing it out for a simple `For()` loop to ensure every iteration is discrete.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. i did try the script with the for() loop but it didnt work and i dont know why :( so i used Nimizen's solution and with a bit of tweaking it seems like its working  ... thanks for your time..

Comment: @Tylendis - No problem, feel free to also upvote either or both of our answers if they've been helpful. Have a great day

Comment: i am actually trying but i need more rep :D . i am at 13 and need at least 15 to do so..